# TemplateDoesNotExist at / - Python, Django, VScode

Tags: python, django, vscode, chrome

Tengo un problema de esos que probablemente se resolverían de una manera muy sencilla pero estoy hace horas intentándolo sin éxito.

La cuestión es que no encuentra la ruta y parece estar todo correctamente configurado.

¿Ideas?

.........

**CÓDIGO:**

*#calc\myapp\views.py*
```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

````
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'calculator/index.html')
    else:
        # Obtenga los valores de los operandos y la operación desde el formulario
        first_operand = int(request.POST['first_operand'])
        second_operand = int(request.POST['second_operand'])
        operation = request.POST['operation']

        # Realice la operación y calcule el resultado
        if operation == 'add':
            result = first_operand + second_operand
        elif operation == 'subtract':
            result = first_operand - second_operand
        elif operation == 'multiply':
            result = first_operand * second_operand
        else:
            result = first_operand / second_operand

        # Agregue la operación y el resultado al historial
        if 'history' not in request.session:
            request.session['history'] = []
        request.session['history'].append({
            'first_operand': first_operand,
            'second_operand': second_operand,
            'operation': operation,
            'result': result,
        })

        # Limite el historial a las últimas 10 operaciones
        if len(request.session['history']) > 10:
            request.session['history'] = request.session['history'][1:]

        return render(request, 'calculator/index.html', {
            'result': result,
            'history': request.session['history'],
        })
```
````

*#calc\myapp\urls.py*
```
"""mysite URL Configuration

````
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

#app_name = 'calculator'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```
````

*#calc\mysite\settings.py*
```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

````
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-7l&=1^(+^#7-pfv!$phza%+v3wuj)5k!=w7x#bt9s4bam914fy'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```
````

*#calc\myapp\templates\calculator\index.html*
`<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %} <input type="text" name="first_operand"> <select name="operation"> <option value="add">+</option> <option value="subtract">-</option> <option value="multiply">*</option> <option value="divide">/</option> </select> <input type="text" name="second_operand"> <button type="submit">Calculate</button> </form> {% if result %} <p>Result: {{ result }}</p> {% endif %} <h2>History</h2> <ul> {% for item in history %} <li>{{ item.first_operand }} {{ item.operation }} {{ item.second_operand }} = {{  item.result }}</li> </ul>`

**#El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:**

---

#En el Google Chrome (http://localhost:8000/):

> ````
> Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ Django Version:  2.2.3
> Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:   
> calculator/index.html Exception
> Location: C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py
> in get_template, line 19 Python
> Executable:   C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.8.2 Python Path:   ['C:\\Projects\\test\\calc', 
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib', 
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32', 
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages', 
> 'C:\\Users\\BCH\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
> Server time:  Sat, 11 Feb 2023 16:38:25 +0000 ```
> ````

---

---

---

#En la consola de comandos de windows:

```
(venv) C:\Projects\test\calc>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you
 apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 11, 2023 - 13:38:20
Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Projects\test\calc\myapp\views.py", line 6, in index
    return render(request, 'calculator/index.html')
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=usi
ng)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: calculator/index.html
[11/Feb/2023 13:38:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 79124
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
[11/Feb/2023 13:38:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50189)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 196, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\simpl
e_server.py", line 38, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 335, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\http\response.py", line 252, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 173, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 174, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\__init__.py", line 57, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 514, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.
py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 145, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 382, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 184, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 288, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 345, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\BCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handl
ers.py", line 358, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
----------------------------------------
```

---

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: tienes las url comentadas en `calc\myapp\urls.py` :v

Comment: No lo veo, lo decís por "#app_name = 'calculator'" ?

Comment: por `urlpatterns` te recomiendo ver un curso o leerte el manual..

Comment: Ah! sí, nono. eso es un error de cuando lo subí a esta web. en el original no estaban comentadas jaja mcuhas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, con 2 o 3 cambios.
-La carpeta templates tenía que "subirla" un lugar en el directorio.
-Y modifiqué la manera de cómo se enlazan las urls, poniendo un urls.py en "myapp" y enlazándola con "path('',include('myapp.urls'))" desde urls.py de "mysite".
-Faltaba un endfor también que fue un error que salió después.

Tal vez me estoy olvidando de algo, pero creo que eso fue lo fundamental.

Gracias.